# Format phone number column in JTable as "(area) prefix-number"

Tags: java, swing, jtable, classcastexception

I am currently using the JDBC to store a phone number that the customer enters into database and then have the phone number displayed in a `JTable`. I am able to get it to work without using the `TableCellRenderer` but I would like the number to appear as (Area) Prefix-Number format in the table. Here is the code that I used to try and achieve this:

```
    //core package
    public class Patient {

        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private String middleName;
        private String lastName;
        private String phneNum;
        private String email;

    public Patient(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String phneNum, String email) {
        this(0, firstName, middleName, lastName, phneNum, email);
    }

    public Patient(int id, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String phneNum, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phneNum = phneNum;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId() {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName() {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName() {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName() {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhneNum() {
        return phneNum;
    }
    public void setPhneNum() {
        this.phneNum = phneNum;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail() {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Patient [id=%s, firstName=%s, middleName=%s, lastName=%s, phneNum=%s, email=%s", 
                id, firstName, middleName, lastName, phneNum, email);
    }

}

public class PhoneNumber {
    public String areaCode;
    public String prefix;
    public String num;

    private PhoneNumber() {}

    public PhoneNumber(String areaCode, String prefix, String num) {
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "areaCode=" + areaCode + "; prefix=" + prefix + "; num=" + num;
    }
}

//DAO Package
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.patientsessiontracker.core.*;

public class PatientDAO {

    private Connection dbConn;

    public PatientDAO() throws Exception {

        // get db properties
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.load(new FileInputStream("Patient Session Tracker Config/patientSessionTracker.properties"));

        String user = config.getProperty("user");
        String password = config.getProperty("password");
        String dburl = config.getProperty("dburl");

        // connect to database
        dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);

        System.out.println("DB connection successful to: " + dburl);
    }

    public void addPatient(Patient thePatient) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement dbStmt = null;

        try {
            //prepare statement
            dbStmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("insert into patients " +
                     "(first_name, middle_name, last_name, phone_number, email) " +
                     "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            // set params
            dbStmt.setString(1, thePatient.getFirstName());
            dbStmt.setString(2, thePatient.getMiddleName());
            dbStmt.setString(3, thePatient.getLastName());
            dbStmt.setObject(4, thePatient.getPhneNum());
            dbStmt.setString(5, thePatient.getEmail());

            // execute the query
            dbStmt.executeUpdate();

        } finally {
            close(dbStmt);
        }
    }

    public List<Patient> getAllPatients() throws Exception {
        List<Patient> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Statement dbStmt = null;
        ResultSet dbRs = null;

        try {
            dbStmt = dbConn.createStatement();
            dbRs = dbStmt.executeQuery("select * from patients");

            while (dbRs.next()) {
                Patient tempPatient = convertRowToPatient(dbRs);
                list.add(tempPatient);
            }

            return list;

        } finally {
            close(dbStmt, dbRs);
        }
    }

    public List<Patient> searchPatients(String firstName, String lastName) throws Exception {
        List<Patient> list = new ArrayList<>();

        PreparedStatement dbStmt = null;
        ResultSet dbRs = null;

        try {
            firstName += "%";
            lastName += "%";
            dbStmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("select * from patients where first_name like ? and last_name like ?");

            dbStmt.setString(1, firstName);
            dbStmt.setString(2, lastName);

            dbRs = dbStmt.executeQuery();

            while (dbRs.next()) {
                Patient tempPatient = convertRowToPatient(dbRs);
                list.add(tempPatient);
            }

            return list;
        } finally {
            close(dbStmt, dbRs);
        }
    }

    private Patient convertRowToPatient(ResultSet dbRs) throws SQLException {

        int id = dbRs.getInt("id");
        String firstName = dbRs.getString("first_name");
        String middleName = dbRs.getString("middle_name");
        String lastName = dbRs.getString("last_name");
        String phneNum = dbRs.getString("phone_number");
        String email = dbRs.getString("email");

        Patient tempPatient = new Patient(firstName, middleName, lastName, phneNum, email);

        return tempPatient;
    }

    private static void close(Connection dbConn, Statement dbStmt, ResultSet dbRs) throws SQLException {
        if (dbRs != null) 
            dbRs.close();

        if (dbStmt != null) 

        if (dbConn != null) 
            dbConn.close();
    }

    private static void close(Statement dbStmt, ResultSet dbRs) throws SQLException {
        close(null, dbStmt, dbRs);
    }

    private void close(Statement dbStmt) throws SQLException {
        close(null, dbStmt, null);      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PatientDAO dao = new PatientDAO();

        System.out.println(dao.getAllPatients());
    }
}

//UI Package
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.util.List;

import com.patientsessiontracker.core.*;
import com.patientsessiontracker.dao.*;

public class PatientSessionTrackerApp extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtFieldSrchFName;
    private JButton btnSearch;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private static JTable table;

    private static PatientDAO patientDAO;
    private JPanel panelBtn;
    private JButton btnAddPatient;
    private JTextField txtFieldSrchLName;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PatientSessionTrackerApp frame = new PatientSessionTrackerApp();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    PatientSessionTrackerApp.refreshPatientsView();
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new PatientSessionTrackerCellRenderer());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public PatientSessionTrackerApp() {

        // create the DAO
        try {
            patientDAO = new PatientDAO();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
        }

        setTitle("Patient Session Tracker");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panelSrch = new JPanel();
        panelSrch.setBounds(5, 5, 579, 33);
        contentPane.add(panelSrch);
        panelSrch.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
        panelSrch.add(lblFirstName);

        txtFieldSrchFName = new JTextField();
        panelSrch.add(txtFieldSrchFName);
        txtFieldSrchFName.setColumns(13);

        btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Get last & first name from the text field

                // Call DAO and get patients for the last & first name

                // If last & first name is empty, then get all patients             

                try {
                    String firstName = txtFieldSrchFName.getText();
                    String lastName = txtFieldSrchLName.getText();

                    List<Patient> patients = null;

                    if (((firstName != null) && (firstName.trim().length() > 0)) ||
                        ((lastName != null) && (lastName.trim().length() > 0))) 
                        patients = patientDAO.searchPatients(firstName, lastName);
                    else
                        patients = patientDAO.getAllPatients();

                    // create the model and update the "table"
                    PatientTableModel model = new PatientTableModel(patients);

                    table.setModel(model);
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new PatientSessionTrackerCellRenderer());

                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PatientSessionTrackerApp.this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                }

            }
        });

        JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
        panelSrch.add(lblLastName);

        txtFieldSrchLName = new JTextField();
        panelSrch.add(txtFieldSrchLName);
        txtFieldSrchLName.setColumns(13);
        panelSrch.add(btnSearch);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(5, 38, 579, 186);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        panelBtn = new JPanel();
        panelBtn.setBounds(5, 224, 579, 38);
        contentPane.add(panelBtn);

        btnAddPatient = new JButton("Add Patient");
        btnAddPatient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // create dialog
                AddPatientDialog addPatient = new AddPatientDialog(PatientSessionTrackerApp.this, patientDAO);

                // show dialog
                addPatient.setModal(true);
                addPatient.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        panelBtn.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        panelBtn.add(btnAddPatient);
    }

    public static void refreshPatientsView() {

        try {
            List<Patient> patients = patientDAO.getAllPatients();

            // create the model and update the "table"
            PatientTableModel model = new PatientTableModel(patients);

            table.setModel(model);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + exc, "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
}

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

import com.patientsessiontracker.core.*;
import com.patientsessiontracker.dao.*;

public class AddPatientDialog extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField txtFieldFName;
    private JTextField txtFieldMName;
    private JTextField txtFieldLName;
    private JTextField txtFieldAreaCode;
    private JTextField txtFieldPhneNum;
    private JTextField txtFieldPhnePrefix;
    private JTextField txtFieldEmail;

    private PatientDAO patientDAO;

    private PatientSessionTrackerApp patientSessionTrackerApp;

    public AddPatientDialog(PatientSessionTrackerApp thePatientSessionTracker, PatientDAO thePatientDAO) {
        this();
        patientDAO = thePatientDAO;
        patientSessionTrackerApp = thePatientSessionTracker;
    }

    public final class LengthRestrictedDocument extends PlainDocument {

          private final int limit;

          public LengthRestrictedDocument(int limit) {
            this.limit = limit;
          }

          @Override
          public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
              throws BadLocationException {
            if (str == null)
              return;

            if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
              super.insertString(offs, str, a);
            }
          }
        }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public AddPatientDialog() {
        setSize(450, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Add New Patient");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);
        {
            JLabel lblFName = new JLabel("<html>First Name<font color='red'>*</font></html>");
            lblFName.setBounds(10, 11, 104, 14);
            contentPanel.add(lblFName);

            txtFieldFName = new JTextField();
            txtFieldFName.setBounds(124, 8, 310, 20);
            contentPanel.add(txtFieldFName);
            txtFieldFName.setColumns(10);

            JLabel lblMName = new JLabel("Middle Name");
            lblMName.setBounds(10, 36, 104, 14);
            contentPanel.add(lblMName);

            txtFieldMName = new JTextField();
            txtFieldMName.setBounds(124, 33, 310, 20);
            contentPanel.add(txtFieldMName);
            txtFieldMName.setColumns(10);

            JLabel lblLName = new JLabel("<html>Last Name<font color='red'>*</font></html>");
            lblLName.setBounds(10, 61, 104, 14);
            contentPanel.add(lblLName);

            txtFieldLName = new JTextField();
            txtFieldLName.setBounds(124, 58, 310, 20);
            contentPanel.add(txtFieldLName);
            txtFieldLName.setColumns(10);

            JLabel lblPhneNum = new JLabel("Phone Number");
            lblPhneNum.setBounds(10, 86, 104, 14);
            contentPanel.add(lblPhneNum);

            JLabel labelLP = new JLabel("(");
            labelLP.setBounds(124, 86, 12, 14);
            contentPanel.add(labelLP);

            txtFieldAreaCode = new JTextField();
            txtFieldAreaCode.setBounds(134, 83, 28, 20);
            contentPanel.add(txtFieldAreaCode);
            txtFieldAreaCode.setColumns(10);
            txtFieldAreaCode.setDocument(new LengthRestrictedDocument(3));
        }

        JLabel labelRP = new JLabel(")");
        labelRP.setBounds(166, 86, 12, 14);
        contentPanel.add(labelRP);

        txtFieldPhneNum = new JTextField();
        txtFieldPhneNum.setBounds(210, 83, 35, 20);
        contentPanel.add(txtFieldPhneNum);
        txtFieldPhneNum.setColumns(10);
        txtFieldPhneNum.setDocument(new LengthRestrictedDocument(4));

        txtFieldPhnePrefix = new JTextField();
        txtFieldPhnePrefix.setColumns(10);
        txtFieldPhnePrefix.setBounds(172, 83, 28, 20);
        contentPanel.add(txtFieldPhnePrefix);
        txtFieldPhnePrefix.setDocument(new LengthRestrictedDocument(3));

        JLabel lblDash = new JLabel("-");
        lblDash.setBounds(202, 83, 12, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblDash);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        {
            JButton okButton = new JButton("Add Patient");
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    savePatient();
                }
            });
            okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        }

        JTextArea txtAddPatientWarning = new JTextArea();
        txtAddPatientWarning.setText("WARNING!!! Once a patient is created it is added to the database and cannot be removed from the database via the Patient Session Tracker. If a patient is added in error, please contact Sudo Technologies at (701) 388-3752.");
        txtAddPatientWarning.setBounds(10, 132, 424, 60);
        txtAddPatientWarning.setEditable(false);
        txtAddPatientWarning.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        txtAddPatientWarning.setLineWrap(true);
        contentPanel.add(txtAddPatientWarning);

        JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
        lblEmail.setBounds(10, 110, 46, 14);
        contentPanel.add(lblEmail);

        txtFieldEmail = new JTextField();
        txtFieldEmail.setColumns(10);
        txtFieldEmail.setBounds(124, 107, 310, 20);
        contentPanel.add(txtFieldEmail);

        JLabel lblRqrdField = new JLabel("<html><font color='red'>*</font> Denotes Required Field</html>");
        lblRqrdField.setBounds(10, 213, 235, 26);
        contentPanel.add(lblRqrdField);
    }

    protected void savePatient() {

        // get the patient info from the gui
        String firstName = txtFieldFName.getText();
        String middleName = txtFieldMName.getText();
        String lastName = txtFieldLName.getText();
        //PhoneNumber phneNum = new PhoneNumber(txtFieldAreaCode.getText(), txtFieldPhnePrefix.getText(), txtFieldPhneNum.getText());
        String areaCode = txtFieldAreaCode.getText();
        String prefix = txtFieldPhnePrefix.getText();
        String num = txtFieldPhneNum.getText();
        String phneNum = areaCode + prefix + num;
        String email = txtFieldEmail.getText();

        Patient tempPatient = new Patient(firstName, middleName, lastName, phneNum, email);

        if ((firstName.trim().length() != 0) && (lastName.trim().length() != 0)) {  

            try{
                // save to the database
                patientDAO.addPatient(tempPatient);

                // close dialog
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();

                // refresh gui list
                patientSessionTrackerApp.refreshPatientsView();

                // show success message
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(patientSessionTrackerApp, "Patient added to the database.", 
                    "Patient Added",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(patientSessionTrackerApp, 
                        "Error saving patient: " +
                        exc.getMessage(), "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } 
        } else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(patientSessionTrackerApp, "<html>Please fill in all required fields as denoted by the <font color='red'>*</font>.</html>");
    }
}

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import com.patientsessiontracker.core.*;

public class PatientSessionTrackerCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String areaCode;
    public String prefix;
    public String num;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, 
                                                   boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        PhoneNumber phneNum = (PhoneNumber) value;
        String text =  "(" + phneNum.areaCode + ") " + phneNum.prefix + "-" + phneNum.num;
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setText(text);
        return this;
    }
}

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import java.util.List;

import com.patientsessiontracker.core.*;

class PatientTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final int FIRST_NAME_COL = 0;
    private static final int MIDDLE_NAME_COL = 1;
    private static final int LAST_NAME_COL = 2;
    private static final int PHONE_NUMBER_COL = 3;
    private static final int EMAIL_COL = 4;

    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", "Email"};

    private List<Patient> patients;

    public PatientTableModel(List<Patient> thePatients) {
        patients = thePatients;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return patients.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

        Patient tempPatient = patients.get(row);

        switch (col) {
        case FIRST_NAME_COL:
            return tempPatient.getFirstName();
        case MIDDLE_NAME_COL:
            return tempPatient.getMiddleName();
        case LAST_NAME_COL:
            return tempPatient.getLastName();
        case PHONE_NUMBER_COL:
            return tempPatient.getPhneNum();
        case EMAIL_COL:
            return tempPatient.getEmail();
        default:
            return tempPatient.getFirstName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
}
```

I tried passing it into the DAO as an object but I haven't found a solution for that yet. When ran I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.patientsessiontracker.core.PhoneNumber
    at com.patientsessiontracker.ui.PatientSessionTrackerCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(PatientSessionTrackerCellRenderer.java:22)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception is telling you, you cannot cast a `String` into a `PhoneNumber` object. Which is happening here when you do this

```
PhoneNumber phneNum = (PhoneNumber) value;
```

You will need a way of parsing a String to your phone number object. Now this can be tricky if you are not forcing the input of the phone number in a particular format. If you are then you could create a method in your `PhoneNumber` to parse a String as a phone number. Something like:

```
public PhoneNumber parsePhoneNumber(String phoneStr){
    // Insert logic to extract your area code, prefix and number
    return new PhoneNumber(aC, pref, num);
}
```

However I see that you are storing your phone number in the database simply as the concatenation of the 3 numbers... this means parsing the string will be near impossible.

You should consider using your `PhoneNumber` object through out your code. For example in your `Patient` rather than a `String`

```
public class Patient {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private PhoneNumber phneNum;
    private String email;

    public Patient(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, PhoneNumber phneNum, String email) {
         this(0, firstName, middleName, lastName, phneNum, email);
    }

    public Patient(int id, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, PhoneNumber phneNum, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phneNum = phneNum;
        this.email = email;
   }
//....
```

Then the only place you need to worry about the conversion is when reading and writing to the database.

Comment: I did try using the PhoneNumber object throughout my code as suggested above. The issue was (as you stated) when I would write it to the database I couldn't use setString for the jdbc parameters. There wouldn't be something as simple as setObject would there (i.e.  under the DAO package addPatient method "dbStmt.setObject(4, thePatient.getPhneNum());")?

Comment: Okay.. The above comment was not a good question. There is a setObject and getObject that can be used. Im thinking on trying to write my own method "getPhoneNumber" or maybe just have the user enter the phone number as one long string and make parsing it easier.

Comment: @EvanPederson You could restrict you user to allow entering digits in three different text fields with the labels for each and then when you read the input store it in the separate phone number fields. You could then either 1) in your database have a field for each phone number field (3 ints) or 2) a single String which is separated by a common delimiter ( such as '-') since the user can only enter Digits. Then you would write to the database as AC-PREF-NUM. When you read it you know to split by '-' and what each section is.

Comment: I almost got the "PatientSessionTrackerCellRenderer" working. I read on how to use customRenderers and I am able to get the phone number to appear as (null) null-null or as a number centered in the cell lol.